# Why does the text on this third column is pushed down?

Tags: html, css

Well, I coded this page, but I got stuck at why does the third column is pushing down my text (or other elements). It uses the same style from the first box, but while the first box is ok, the third one is pushing the elements down by some pixels.

Like this:

[image: this gap it's freaking me out]

HTML

```
<div id="contentWrapper">
    <div id="sideBar">
        <div class="sidebarBox"></div>
        <div class="sidebarContent">
            <h4>
                Índice
            </h4>
            <ul class="tree">
                <li>
                    <a href="#sinopse">Sinopse</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#tropas">Tropas</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Geladeira</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#logica">Lógica</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#genio">Gênio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="last">
                            <a href="#horror">Horror</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#notas">Notas</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#midia">Mídia</a>
                </li>
                <li class="last">
                    <a href="#referencias">Referências</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainBody"></div>
    <div id="infoBar">
        <div class="sidebarBox"></div>3º Column
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font:normal normal 14px/20px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

h4 {
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:700;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding-top:10px;
    border-bottom:2px solid #2a558c;
    margin-bottom:10px
}

#contentWrapper {
    display:table;
    border-spacing:0;
    width:100%;
    height:500px
}

#contentWrapper > div {
    display:table-cell
}

#sideBar {
    background-color:#E4E5DD;
    width:200px
}

#mainBody {
    background-color:#EEEEE6
}

#infoBar {
    background-color:#e4e5dd;
    width:200px
}

#footer {
    background-color:#323540;
    height:50px
}

.sidebarBox {
    background-color:#323540;
    height:30px;
    width:100%
}

.sidebarContent {
    padding:15px
}
```

I messed a lot with the Firebug and even tried to open it in IE and Chrome, with same results. Both columns use the same CSS, and this difference is freaking me out. I thought about "fixing" it with some negative margins, but I want to understand the problem first, insted of "workahacking" away.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please create jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ so your code can be accessed and modified right online;

Comment: @d.sergeiev I agree. But here it is. http://jsfiddle.net/nbbVg/

Comment: That's probably because of some Table sin.

Comment: Table layout is bad in many ways, it hits the fan here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html and in many other places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to `#contentWrapper > div`. Currently it is `baseline`.

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/nbbVg/3/)

CSS

```
#contentWrapper > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Without `vertical-align: top`, the `div` is basing its vertical alignment on `.sidebarContent` which has 15px of padding. This is resulting in the 15px gap.

Answer (score 3):

Change the following and it should fix your problem.  I've found that when using `display:table-cell` it always mis-aligns the last cell unless I specifically give it a vertical alignment

```
#contentWrapper > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/nbbVg/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline-block` to this class:

```
.sidebarBox {
    background-color: #323540;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;/*Add this*/
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nbbVg/1/)

Comment: Explain the downvote. Tested in all browsers and works.

Comment: inline-block to display divs next to eah other gives some extra troubles in a lot of browsers because of the whitespace: http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block

Comment: Did you test it on others browsers?

Comment: did you read the link? inline-block for positioning of block elements is a neat trick, but should be avoided. Better would be to use float with clear-floats on the parent:after pseudo element

Comment: This method relies on there being a `<div class="sidebarBox">`. If `.sidebarBox` is removed (which it should be, it should be a border, not a `div`) then there is still a padding problem. This method is just covering up the problem.

Comment: This method works fine for this example. Thx for feedback anyway guys :)

Comment: misterManSam, sidebarBox is a div 'coz later I will add content to it. It's not there just for showing...

Answer (score -1):

```
.sidebarBox {
    float:right;
}
```

will work.

Comment: This method relies on there being a `<div class="sidebarBox">`. If `.sidebarBox` is removed (which it should be, it should be a border, not a `div`) then there is still a padding problem. This method is just covering up the problem.